# Pulling unique values with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, unique

I have 3 columns in a table: Column A has id numbers (500 different unique numbers), B has ranking (rank 1 to 500), and C has years (2011 to 2020).

[image]

I want to extract to a new table that lists 50 numbers by ranking across the 10 years, from greatest to least for each year; i.e. pull in all unique values that are of that same year or older. 
[image]

My formula for the first year column is straightforward: `=LARGE(IF('Sale Candidates'!$O$7:$O$797<=C$2,'Sale Candidates'!$D$7:$D$797),$B3)` ; where $O$7:$O$797 is the years from the main data table, and $D$7:$D$797 the ranking from the main data table.

It's the columns that come after that I'm having difficulty with. How can I pull in unique values for the 2nd year and on, so that it's not pulling in values that were already pulled in the prior columns?

Comment: How often do you need to run this task? if it is a one off it would be just as quick using the sort function, sort by Year then sort by rank highest to lowest, manually copy and paste the data. Otherwise you could record a macro to sort the data then apply a filter by date, copy the data and repeat for each year, this can then be used over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to introduce another condition to check if the number has been used before

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(($C$2:$C$11<=F$1)*(COUNTIF($E$2:E11,$B$2:$B$11)=0),$B$2:$B$11),$A2),"")
```

entered as an array formula starting in F2 and assuming the first column of largest numbers starts in E2.

Or you could do it with AGGREGATE

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$11/(($C$2:$C$11=F$1)*(COUNTIF($E$2:E$11,$B$2:$B$11)=0)),$A2),"")
```

which doesn't have to be entered as an array formula.

[image]